# Setting $invalid and $error doesn't invalidate the form

Tags: angularjs, validation, typescript, intl-tel-input

I have a form which I'm in the process of changing my phone fields from using a regex to the intl-tel-input module. I'm running into problems & confusion in checking for valid #s.

I have a form with several of these fields...

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <label for="cellPhone"
           translate>CONTACT.CELL</label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6"
     ng-class="{'has-error': !cellPhoneFocus && forms.contactForm.cellPhone.$invalid && forms.contactForm.cellPhone.$touched }">
    <input type="text" class="form-control intlPhoneInput"
           id="cellPhone" name="cellPhone"
           ng-model="contact.cellPhone.display"
           ng-focus="cellPhoneFocus = true"
           ng-blur="cellPhoneFocus = false; validatePhone($event)">
    <div ng-messages="forms.contactForm.cellPhone.$error"
         ng-show="!cellPhoneFocus && forms.contactForm.cellPhone.$touched"
         class="errorMessages">
        <p ng-message="pattern" translate>
            CRUD.VALID_PHONE</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the submit...

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="forms.contactForm.$invalid" id="saveContactLink" translate>CRUD.SAVE</button>
```

Then in my controller (Typescript)...

```
//In Constructor
$scope.validatePhone = this.validatePhone.bind(this);

//Outside constructor
private validatePhone(eventObject: any) {
    let thePhoneField = $('#' + eventObject.target.id);
    let phoneIsValid = thePhoneField.intlTelInput("isValidNumber");

    this.$scope.forms.contactForm[eventObject.target.id].$invalid = !phoneIsValid;
    this.$scope.forms.contactForm[eventObject.target.id].$error = {"pattern": !phoneIsValid};
}
```

This properly sets my has-error class and error message, but it doesn't set the FORM to invalid. I've tried $setValidity...

```
this.$scope.forms.contactForm[eventObject.target.id].$setValidity('pattern', !phoneIsValid);
```

...but it doesn't seem to do anything at all.

How do I set the field to invalid, show the correct ng-message(if there's more than one), and make sure the form $errors gets updated so the submit is disabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out $setValidity WAS working, but having setValidity along with .$invalid and $error caused some crossed wires. Commenting out the last two enabled/disabled my submit button correctly when invalidating a field.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to set the form to invalid like so:

```
forms.contactForm.$invalid = true
```

Comment: While that will invalidate the form, it doesnt help make it valid when the field is fixed, as I cant simply do an else on validatePhone to set the form to valid...as there's more than one field.